# Powershell-LDAP Add User

Tags: powershell, ldap

I have now written a script, which should create a new User-Object in the >>LDAP<< (not AD).
It returns no errors but the user is not created...

```
$authenticationType  = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::ServerBind
$obj = new-object system.directoryservices.directoryEntry ($Container, "uid=user,ou=ed,o=company", "password" ,  $authenticationType) 
$newobj = $obj.PSBase.Children.Add([string]$RDN,[string]$Class)
$obj.PSBase.CommitChanges()
```

I call my Function with $RDN which is the username, $class="user" and $container ("LDAP://server.com:999/ou=user,o=company") the path where the object should be created.

I hope someone can help me ;)

Greets
Madeye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

I combined ADSI: and Directory:Entry to get to my Solution.

Greetz Madeye